# Reference Request: Standard trace on $C^*(G)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $G$ be a discrete group and consider its group $C^*$-algebra, $C^*(G)$.

In some bibliography I've seen the term "let $tr$ be the standard trace on $C^*(G)$", but I'm not sure what it means, however from the context seems to be implied that it verifies the following propery.

Let $u:G \rightarrow C^*(G)$ be the universal representation, then
$$
tr(u_g) = \begin{cases}
1 \quad &\text{if } g = e \\
0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the standard trace on $C^*(G)$ and do you know a reference for it?
2. Does it verify the above property?

In the commutative case, one can use the Gelfand transform to show that $C^*(G) \cong C(\widehat G)$. Let $\phi_g$ be the image of $u_g$ under this isomorphism.

3. In the commutative setting, do $tr$ and this isomorphism induce a trace $\rho: C(\widehat G) \rightarrow \mathbb C$, such that for all $g \in G$,

$$
\rho(\phi_g)= \int_{\widehat G} \, \chi(g)d\mu(\chi),
$$
where $\mu$ is the normalized Haar measure on $\widehat G$? If question 2) is true, then this means in particular that
$$
\rho(\phi_g) = \begin{cases}
1 \quad &\text{if } g = e \\
0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

PS: If given a reference I can probably work the rest out on my own, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a standard trace on $C^*(G)$, but to describe it, we first describe the standard trace of $C^*_r(G)$.

Recall that the left regular representation of $G$ is the unitary representation $\lambda:G\to B(\ell^2G)$, given by $g\mapsto\lambda_g$, where $\lambda_g:\ell^2G\to\ell^2G$ is the unitary operator satisfying $\lambda_g(\xi_t)=\xi_{gt}$, where $\{\xi_t\}_{t\in G}$ is the canonical orthonormal basis of $\ell^2G$. The reduced group $C^*$-algebra of $G$ is by definition $C^*_r(G):=\overline{\text{span}}\{\lambda_g:g\in G\}\subset B(\ell^2(G))$.

Now $C^*_r(G)$ admits a standard trace, given by $\tau:C^*_r(G)\to\mathbb{C}$, $\tau(x)=\langle x\xi_{1_G},\xi_{1_G}\rangle_{\ell^2G}$. It is easy to check that $\tau$ is indeed a trace; Moreover, $\tau(\lambda_g)=\langle\xi_g,\xi_{1_G}\rangle=\delta_{g,1_G}$ (Kronecker delta).

Exercise: show that $\tau$ is faithful, i.e. $\tau(x^*x)=0\implies x=0$ for any $x\in C^*_r(G)$

(**hint**: there is a right regular representation of $G$ on $\ell^2G$ as well, and it has commuting range with the left regular rep).

By the universal property of $C^*(G)$, we have a canonical surjection $q:C^*(G)\to C^*_r(G)$ satisfying $q(u_g)=\lambda_g$ for all $g\in G$. Considering $\tau\circ q:C^*(G)\to\mathbb{C}$, we obtain a trace on $C^*(G)$ (check that it is a trace) mapping $u_g$ to $\delta_{g,1_G}$.

The reference I would give for this is Brown-Ozawa, 2.5. Check also Blackadar's encyclopedia on Operator algebras; otherwise Ken Davidson's "$C^*$-algebras by example", chapter VII is a good source.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I knew about the trace of $C^*_r(G)$, however was misled to think that if $G$ isn't amenable, then procedure you did wouldn't work, but now I understand that it simply means that the trace on $C^*(G)$ isn't necessarily faithful, am I correct?

Now let's assume $G$ is commutative (hence amenable), does the formula of question 3 hold? I would say that integration is the most natural trace to consider but am not being able to prove it.

Comment: @TomásPacheco That's right, if $G$ is not amenable, then this trace will fail to be faithful (why: $q$ is not injective; thus $\ker(q)$ contains non-zero positive elements, which all will have trace zero for this trace). For question 3, just check that the trace on $C(\hat{G})$ coming from integration w.r.t the Haar measure on the Pontryagin dual maps $u_g$ to $\delta_{g,1_G}$. Then you have two linear maps agreeing on a set that spans a dense subspace, thus they are equal

Comment: Thank you again! I am struggling to show that integration maps ug to δe, do you know any hints? Thanks in advance.